# jwt_session rails 6 token expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I
f I set JWTSessions.refresh_exp_time = 180, I can max. refresh the token after 3 minutes from login, no matter how many times it was refreshed before?

The refresh time is not increased when I refresh a token. Am i right?

jwt_session 2.5.2 rails 6.1.3

Answer (score 1):

It will refresh the token every time you call refreshtoken. And simply put, the 3 minutes countdown is restarted.

Comment: I know we have two tokens, access and refresh. If I refresh the access token, should the time for refreshing also increase, or the time for refreshing is still the same. I have the impression that it is all the time the same, even after refreshing. If I set for example acces for 90 seconds and refresh for 120 seconds, then after 90 seconds I refresh the token and it is ok, and after another 90 seconds it does not work anymore.